# Converting XML to CSV for AD Import (Use of Wildcard)

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, active-directory

I am attempting to convert XML from an API call to a CSV that can be used to create AD users. So far, it mostly works, except for the mobile phone value.

Here is what the XML looks like.

```
<first_name>SomeName</first_name>
<nick_first_name>SomeFirstName</nick_first_name>
<nick_name>SomeNickName</nick_name>
<middle_name>SomeMiddleName</middle_name>
<last_name>SomeLastName</last_name>
<name_suffix/>
<gender>Female</gender>
<birthday type="date">1901-01-01</birthday>
<email_1 display="true">myemail@example.com</email_1>
<home_phone display="true"/>
<mobile_phone display="false">555-555-5555</mobile_phone>
```

Here is my Powershell

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\page1.xml'
$xml.SelectNodes('//facstaff') |
Select-Object @{n='name';e={$_.first_name + " " + $_.last_name}},
            @{n='SAM';e={$_.first_name + $_.last_name}},
            @{n='mobile';e={$_.mobile_phone}},
            @{n='password';e={"TestPassword1"}} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\page1.csv' -NoType -Delimiter ';'

Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\page1.csv"  
foreach ($User in $Users)  
{  
$OU = "OU=FacultyStaff,DC=informacast,DC=us"  
$Password = $User.password 
$Detailedname = $User.name
$SAM = $User.SAM
$Mobile = $User.mobile
New-ADUser -Name $Detailedname -MobilePhone $Mobile -SamAccountName $SAM -
UserPrincipalName $SAM -DisplayName $Detailedname -GivenName $user.firstname -
Surname $user.name -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -
AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path $OU  
}
```

At this point, it runs, and creates the users. However, when I check the account, everyone has the value of "mobile_phone" where their actual number should be. I think it has something to do with the property of "display="false"" in the XML, but I don't know how to progress. I tried to use * as a wildcard value like this:

```
@{n='mobile';e={$_.mobile_phone*}},
```

but that didn't work. Any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `@{n='mobile';e={$_.mobile_phone.'#text'}}` to get the inner text from your mobile_phone node.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I am just learning this, and the smallest things trip me up.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - You may like to put it as an answer so that OP can accept the same, and others can get help from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, I should have made this an answer not a comment. With XML in PowerShell if you're looking for the inner text of a node you can reference its `'#text'` property. In this case updating the line to the following will resolve the issue:

```
@{n='mobile';e={$_.mobile_phone.'#text'}}
```